# Amazon Kinesis can't find main class in Flink job compiled with Maven

Tags: amazon-web-services, maven, amazon-kinesis

Trying to execute a Flink job, compiled with Maven, in Amazon Kinesis Data Analytics and I get the following error:

"org.apache.flink.client.program.ProgramInvocationException: Neither a 'Main-Class', nor a 'program-class' entry was found in the jar file."

I have tried several ways of defining the main class in the pom.xml-file.

Right now it looks like this:

```
<transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
  <manifestEntries>
    <Main-Class>com.dataductus.maven.time_aggregator.TimeAggregator</Main-Class>
  </manifestEntries>
</transformer>
```

Here is the pom.xml (the code gets weird when I format it in the comment):

https://textuploader.com/1cq7k

Here is the plugin:

https://textuploader.com/1cq7j

I use "mvn package" to package.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You don't show the entire plugin configuration, or the command that you use to build the JAR, or the contents of the manifest file (if any), so there are many possible causes.

However, my *guess* is that you're using an older version of the plugin, so that the documentation [here](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/examples/resource-transformers.html#ManifestResourceTransformer) (which you seem to be following) may not apply.

The easiest solution is to follow the documentation [here](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/examples/executable-jar.html), has an explicit `mainClass` entry. I can assure you that works; I've been using it for at least ten years.

Comment: I updated my question. Unfortunaly, I tried updating the version of the shade-plugin and it didnt work. Also tried using the exakt code from your later link, didnt work.

Comment: @user9692590 - in that case you need to start working through the process. First thing to check is whether the JAR file in the `target` directory has a correct manifest (and note that the Shade plugin leaves the original JAR in the directory, but renames it). Then you need to verify that you're actually using the JAR that you think your are.

Comment: Ok. The manifest seems to say that it denotes where my main class is:  <br/>
Manifest-Version: 1.0<br/>
Archiver-Version: Plexus Archiver<br/>
Built-By: ductus<br/>
Created-By: Apache Maven 3.6.0<br/>
Build-Jdk: 1.8.0_252<br/>
Main-Class: com.dataductus.maven.time_aggregator.TimeAggregator
<br/>
I get two jars in target:

time_aggregator-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar, and

original-time_aggregator-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar

I am using the first one.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you I will look at that.

Here is the pom.xml (the code gets weird when I format it in the comment):

https://textuploader.com/1cq7k

Here is the plugin:

https://textuploader.com/1cq7j

I use "mvn package" to package.

Comment: You should edit your original question rather than adding your own answer or pasting large amounts of text in comments. And please format any code blocks, *GBouffard* did for your original post.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. No idea what was wrong. I created another identical KDA-app which used the exact same jar and now it works. Strange.